# SQL: Is it possible to convert dd-mon-yy to a time of day?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have this table called appointments with dd-mon-yy dates:

```
APP_DATE  
--------- 
06-NOV-20 
06-NOV-20
```

My teacher wants us to convert it to this:

```
APPT_DATE      APPT_TIME 
-------------  ------------
NOV 06, 2020   10:45 AM 
NOV 06, 2020   11:30 AM
```

Is this even possible? If so, how? My teacher didn't give us hourly information in appointments. But maybe it's still present because they are date types?

Comment: What data type is `app_date`?

Comment: it's a DATE data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is a `date`, then it contains a time, and it's only a matter of [*displaying*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96) it:

```
select to_char(app_date, 'Mon, d yyyy') as app_date, 
       to_char(app_date, 'hh24:mi') as app_time
from the_table;
```

Comment: ***There is a small typo though. Should be 'hh24:mi' on second line.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally only have a date, there is no way to obtain appointment time.

If that is a view or some kind of presentation layer, and there is actually a DATETIME format in the underlying data source you could use something like:
`CONVERT(TIME(0), APP_DATE) AS APP_TIME`

If that's not the case, it seems like your teacher has missed some key info, and/ or is more interested in changing the date format from DD-MMM-YY to [MMM DD, YYYY]
This can be done as :
`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, APP_DATE, 107)`

See this link for more info about CONVERT function and format options:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: That syntax is not valid for Oracle (there is no `convert` function or a `time` data type). Plus: Oracle's `DATE` does include a time part.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ah OK, that tag wasn't there when I answered

Comment: @JShark: yes, but `sqlplus` only works with Oracle..

Comment: @NotARobot - Added the syntax for SQL Server to my answer, but I hadn't realised you're using Oracle.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should have made that more clear. But, since it was a DATE data type in my table, it turns out that you can get an exact time based on hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer ticked as correct has some issues.

You can use the following code:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(APP_DATE, 'Mon, DD yyyy') AS APP_DATE, -- use DD instead of D
       TO_CHAR(APP_DATE,'hh24:mi') AS APP_TIME -- Use 24 instead of 42
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Yeah your right. There are no errors in your code. Accept the other guy's answer is still close enough I feel.